# Changing Swiffy Ad Size

Tags: javascript, html, flash, google-swiffy

I've got an ad with the size is 728x90 which was converted from Flash to Html5 using [Google Swiffy](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/?hl=en).

Myself, I've never used flash. I've done some creative campaigns in the past on GDN, but I've built them directly using Html5. Anyway, I was asked if I can convert that 728x90 flash-built-converted-to-html5-with-swiffy ad to 835x90 format.

After opening the document, I've noticed an Object literal `swiffyobject = {...}` which is passed as parameter to the `Stage()` method which resides in Google's `runtime.js` [library](https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js). This method apparently returns an object on which we call another method `start()` to make the magic happen:

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {});

      stage.start();
```

The object literal `swiffyobject` seems for me the right place to start in order to change the ad size. However, the most relevant part I found regarding changing the size is at the start, `ymax` & `xmax`:

```
swiffyobject = {
            "as3": false,
            "frameRate": 20,
            "frameCount": 1,
            "backgroundColor": -1,
            "frameSize": {
                "ymin": 0,
                "xmin": 0,
                "ymax": 1800,
                "xmax": 15560
            },
            ...
        }
```

Since the height of the ad wilm remain the same and only the width is the problem, scaling up `xmax` to `17846` will change the add size but not in a way we desire, instead, for some reason, it shrinks the ad's height by approximately 4px.

Any idea where should I tackle this great `swiffyobject` (which after re-indented with my IDE has approximately 6000 lines) in order to change the ad size? Or is there any online convertor that solves this?

Comment: I'd suggest rebuilding the Flash ad in native HTML5 - this will probably be a lot quicker ( and also more versatile to size changes in the future ). Other than that, I would change the size in Flash and then re-convert it back to HTML5 with Swiffy. I wouldn't want to touch that hideous output even with a 10 feet pole.

Comment: @kevinMario Inevitably, that's exactly what I did. The only problem, at that time, was that I couldn't get a hold of the flash files. However that was solved and life went by :)

Comment: it's always nice when life does that :) case closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable solution, other than completely remaking the ad in HTML5, was to get a hold of the flash files, resize them & reconvert them. Touching that swiffy object just creates a big mess and a headache.

Answer (score 0):

in your html, there should be a part like that:

```
<div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 728px; height: 90px">
</div>
```

do you also change it to 835? If not, swiffy may think it's a 835x90 flash in a 728x90 container, and scale it to fit the container.

Comment: Yes, I've done that, it increases the ad's container size, but not the ad content itself.